# IAM create policy allowing only one region but all global services nesseary

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I would love to limited usage of an AWS account to one region but still allowing the global services and especially Cloudfront (which needs ACM in N. Virginia).

The following simple statement is not enough for my purpose:

```
{
    "Sid": "DisableRegions",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": "*",
    "Resource": "*",
    "Condition": {
        "StringNotEquals": {
            "aws:RequestedRegion": [
                "eu-central-1"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Has anybody a working version of an IAM policy doing exactly that? Please also consider S3, buckets should be only available in this region as well!

Comment: Have you tried creating one ? You can use https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html

Comment: Yes I did, but the big questions it how to handle the global services and ... which are there.

Comment: IAM itself is global, so as other AWS services such as S3. So they are automatically handled.

Answer (score 4):

My solution now allows admin access to Frankfurt and enables all global services. For S3 I only allow global read only access. ACM has to be allowed in North Virginia as well to enable SSL in Cloudfront. Feedback is always welcome!

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AdministratorAccessForRegionFrankfurt",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestedRegion": [
                        "eu-central-1"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowGlobalServices",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "aws-portal:*",
                "awsbillingconsole:*",
                "iam:*",
                "sts:*",
                "health:*",
                "support:*",
                "budgets:*",
                "cloudfront:*",
                "organizations:*",
                "trustedadvisor:*",
                "shield:*",
                "waf:*",
                "waf-regional:*",
                "route53:*",
                "route53domains:*",
                "tag:*",
                "resource-groups:*",
                "s3:Get*",
                "s3:List*",
                "s3:Head*",
                "glacier:List*",
                "glacier:Describe*",
                "glacier:Get*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowACMInUSEastAsWell",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "acm:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestedRegion": [
                        "us-east-1"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this worked perfectly for me as well.

Comment: Keep in mind this is no golden bullet, as services change.